# What movie was based on ‘Inverted World’ by Christopher Priest?

Tags: movie, story-identification

I've started reading Christopher Priest's [*Inverted World*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inverted_World_%28novel%29), and from the first page I realized that I have seen a movie which had the same plot. But I cannot remember the title of the movie.

Here’s a short description of the story:

> A closed world, more like a city, where people don't know about what's happening outside. There is a drive everyone has to maintain in order to keep city alive. But then a young boy, one of the drive engineers realizes that there is something outside the city, so he fights his way out.

Does anyone recognize this movie?

Comment: When you finished the book did you realise that the movie wasn't really anything like *Inverted World*z

Comment: Yup, true. The book was fantastic. The film was ok :)

Comment: Are you asking for a movie based on Priest's novel, or just some film where things aren't as they seem and eventually we find out what's going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like [City of Ember](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0970411/) to me.

City of Ember film is based of The City of Ember novel (and the city doesn't move for one thing). It sounds though like there are thematic similarities between the two novels, but this is not an actual adaptation.

Comment: Hmm In that case its not a direct adaptation - City of Ember film is based of The City of Ember novel (and the city doesn't move for one thing). It sounds though like there are thematic similarities between the two novels. _Added for completeness for future viewers_

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a bit like [Dark City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_City_%281998_film%29)?

Comment: no, I know Dark City. And it's not it.

Comment: Lots of conceptual similarities though

Comment: Not likely. Just the vague notion that "there's something that we don't know" doesn't really seem sufficient to claim a relationship between the two.

Comment: Could you please expand on this? How exactly does this match the description?

Answer (score -2):

**It's *Snowpiercer*!**

Set in a future where a failed climate-change experiment kills all life on the planet except for a lucky few who boarded the Snowpiercer, a train that travels around the globe, where a class system emerges.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706620/

Comment: Certainly not. Sorry, but apart from the train the two have nothing in common, and most particularly Snowpiercer does not feature the mathematical peculiarities inherent in Priest's novel.