# Movie about earth without light

Tags: story-identification, movie

It is a science fiction Hollywood movie story about earth in which people live inside the earth, where no light is present. One day a boy and a girl find the way to get on the surface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What movie was based on ‘Inverted World’ by Christopher Priest?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-movie-was-based-on-inverted-world-by-christopher-priest)

Comment: Yeah, almost certainly [City of Ember](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0970411/).

Comment: Very likely, but not certainly. Give the OP a chance to answer.

Answer (score 6):

[City of Ember (2008)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Ember), based on the 2003 novel The City of Ember by Jeanne DuPrau.

> In the midst of an unspecified catastrophe which is destroying human
>   civilization and polluting the environment, an underground city is
>   constructed to shelter a large group of survivors. The "Builders" of
>   the underground "City of Ember" place secret instructions to future
>   generations in a small box timed to open in exactly 200 years after
>   the event. The City of Ember is built into a vast and gigantic
>   underground cavern and is filled with conventionally sized 3 to
>   4-story buildings and houses. Far above the tops of the buildings are
>   banks of floodlights that light the city during the day and provide
>   light for the greenhouses. The lights are powered by a massive
>   generator.
>
> 200 years after the apocalypse...Ember threatens to fall into darkness as the main
>   generator begins to fail. Blackouts are occurring with increasing
>   frequency and last longer each time. The reserves of canned goods and
>   light bulbs are also becoming depleted. Much of the knowledge about
>   how to use and repair the systems necessary for the city's survival
>   has also slowly been lost over succeeding generations, as the
>   knowledge was passed through spoken words rather than written.
>
> It's left to two young adults to unearth the secret of Ember and to
>   lead the way out.

[image]