# Book about people living in a city in a ravine

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book where the people live in some sort of communist community in a very deep ravine. It's so deep that they think the sun doesn't shine anymore. They have a lot of supplies to stay in the ravine for years.
The story starts at a point that the resources/supplies are running low and one person starts to think what they should do next. Eventually the main character escapes from the ravine and finds that there are still people living outside of it.

The community in the ravine is very happy with the way they live there so most of them don't want to go outside of the city or leave the ravine. They have a very dictatorial mayor who tries to keep everyone inside the city. Most of them are left behind in the city.

As far as I can recall the main character is girl living with her grandma.

It has been several years ago since I read the book. And I think it was written for teenagers/young adults.

I read the book in Dutch, but it was a translated version.
I got the book from the local library but they don't have it anymore and don't have old records of me (as in older then 5 years old).

Comment: Is there anything sci-fi/fantasy about the book? Maybe a nuclear war? Apocalypse? Alien invasion? Magic lighting? ESP?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. I hope you decide to stick around!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots in the beginning you don't know that they live inside a ravine, they just live in a dark post-apocalyptic world where they think the sun has burned up.

Comment: Sounds like City of Ember a little?

Comment: @Strobe_ that's it :D thanks a lot if you post it as an answer i can mark it as answer

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-movie-was-based-on-inverted-world-by-christopher-priest (about the movie version)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[City of Ember](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/307791.The_City_of_Ember)* is what you're looking for.

> Many hundreds of years ago, the city of Ember was created by the Builders to contain everything needed for human survival. It worked…but now the storerooms are almost out of food, crops are blighted, corruption is spreading through the city and worst of all—the lights are failing. Soon Ember could be engulfed by darkness…
>
> But when two children, Lina and Doon, discover fragments of an ancient parchment, they begin to wonder if there could be a way out of Ember. Can they decipher the words from long ago and find a new future for everyone? Will the people of Ember listen to them?

And it's only the first book in a [pretty big series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40332-book-of-ember).

Comment: :) Can you expand a little on your answer, how it matches what they're looking for, maybe linking it to Goodreads or Wikipedia?

Comment: I saw there is a movie maid of it, do you know by any chance if it's a good one?

Comment: I didn't mind the movie and it did a good job of visualising what I had imagined the city to be like from the books, but the acting was a little weak. Definitely worth a watch if you enjoyed the book.

Comment: @Strobe_ yeah i'm def gonna watch it and reread the book (and read the other books for the first time)